# Convert ArrayBuffers to List in Case Class that uses Seq

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have case classes

```
case class Y(y1: Seq[String])
case class X(x1: Seq[Int], x2: Seq[Y])
```

I may have a object X where all the Seq's are ArrayBuffers. How could I recreate my object X, changing all the ArraysBuffers to Lists? I need to do this generically!

Is this the sort of thing which could be done using Shapeless?

Comment: What is it you are _actually_ trying to achieve? This sounds like an XY-problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but probably simple `copy()` can help you

```
val ax = X(mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Int], mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Y])
val bx = ax.copy(x1 = ax.x1.toList, x2 = ax.x2.toList)
```

output

```
ax: X = X(ArrayBuffer(),ArrayBuffer())
bx: X = X(List(),List())
```

Comment: I know I can do this, what I want to do is do this generically